# React.js component: user defined properties. Am i doing it right?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just started learning React, and i'd like to know how to store some arbitrary variables. Let's take the following example:

```
var StaffRow = React.createClass({
    doubleClickTimeout: null,
    waitingForDoubleClick: false,
    doubleClick: function(e){
        console.log('doubleClick');
    },
    singleClick: function(e){
        console.log('singleClick');
    },

    clickHandler: function(e){
        if(this.waitingForDoubleClick)
        {
            this.waitingForDoubleClick = false;
            clearTimeout(this.doubleClickTimeout);
            this.doubleClick(e);
        } else {
            this.waitingForDoubleClick = true;
            this.doubleClickTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                this.waitingForDoubleClick = false;
                this.singleClick(e);
            }.bind(this), 300);
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        var name = "Some Name";
        return (
            <li onClick={this.clickHandler} >
                <span>{name}</span>
            </li>
        );
    }
});
```

I'm implementing a click/doubleclick handler. This works just fine, but i'd like to know, if this is the correct way to store some random properties (doubleClickTimeout and waitingForDoubleClick), or are there some caveats to polluting the React component instance, which i'm not aware of? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not required, I'd remove lines 2 and 3:

```
doubleClickTimeout: null,
waitingForDoubleClick: false,
```

And set them in componentWillMount.  The reason is if these are object/arrays, they'll be shared by all instances using the above, while componentWillMount is a function so they'll be clean references.

```
componentWillMount: function(){
    this.doubleClickTimeout = null;
    this.waitingForDoubleClick = false;
}
```

The rule of thumb is if it affects render, it must be in state or props.  Otherwise an instance property is the way to go.